# vue proxy access nginx server_name

Tags: nginx, proxy, vue.js

my code as below:

1. webpack.dev.config.js

   ```
   devServer: {
       port: config.port,
       proxy: config.proxy
   }
   ```
2. config.js

   ```
   module.exports = {
       port: 8099,
       proxy: {
           "/api/v1/*": "http://192.168.1.11", //it is proxy by nginx, not works
           // "/api/v1/*": "http://192.168.1.11:8033", //access tomcat directly, it works
       }
   };
   ```
3. nginx.conf

   ```
   upstream tomcat {
       server 127.0.0.1:8033 weight=10 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s;
   }
   server {
       listen                   80;
       server_name     192.168.1.11;
       location / {
           proxy_next_upstream     http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 error timeout invalid_header;
           proxy_pass              http://tomcat;
           expires                 0;
       }
       location /logs/ {
           autoindex       off;
           deny all;
       }
   }
   ```

and then I startup my frontend server, and test, I get the request header as below:

```
    POST /api/v1/login HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8099
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 25
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Origin: http://localhost:8099
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Referer: http://localhost:8099/
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7
```

look over the request header, "Host" is "localhost:8099", it is not my nginx proxy, so it can't access to my nginx proxy server; my nginx log also has no access record, I want to know I can I resolve it? Thanks a lot!!
By the way, My English is poor, if you can't understand me, I'm sorry.

Comment: Try adding `proxy_set_header Host $host` to your `location /`

Comment: Hi Tarun, I have added this configure, it seems no use for this problem